# Oxygen Uptake Rates in Microbial Cultures

Tags: microbiology, bacteriology, microbiome

Normally if air is sparged into a fermenter, the oxygen uptake rate is roughly equivalent to the oxygen transfer rate:

K<sub>L</sub>a(C* - C<sub>L</sub>) = Xμ/Y<sub>X/O<sub>2</sub></sub>.

How would this equation change if the oxygen became limiting (DO < 0.3 mg-O<sub>2</sub>/L)?

Comment: If you share with us your background research, it would be useful to the community, and also help us understand your question

Comment: I know under steady state conditions (ie when oxygen transfer is limiting) the OUR = OTR - this i know from background research. But if the dissolved oxygen drops below the critical dissolved oxygen concentration wouldn't that change the above expression?

Comment: Also, please explain the equation; explain what the symbols denote (what are the constants/variables).